# synchronize two javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to synchronize two javascript function which uses the same variable.like say for example `i` is a variable and its initial value is `zero` first function increase this value by `1` and other one decrease the value by `1` but **after the first function call only**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide what u try

Comment: Do you mean you can't guarantee when the first function is called because it's in an async function? Your question doesn't make sense without more context, since functions are sync by default.

Comment: yes i want sync function but after the 1st function change the value 2nd one would not be executed... @DominicTobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set timeout between two function.. May be what u want is this...

```
<html>
<script>
var i=0;
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {

    }, 10);
}, 30); 
function loop() {
    var args = arguments;
    if (args.length <= 0)
        return;
    (function chain(i) {
        if (i >= args.length || typeof args[i] !== 'function')
            return;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            args[i]();
            chain(i + 1);
        }, 2000);
    })(0);
} 
function abc(){
//console.log("kishan");
i++;
console.log(i);
}
function def(){
//console.log("oza");
i--;
console.log(i);
}

for(var u =0 ;u<5;u++){
loop(abc,def);
}

</script>
</html>
```